# Error using data in Wilcoxon test

Tags: r

I am trying to apply Wilcoxon test. Basically I read the data and labels from csv files as the following code shows:

```
fmeasures <- read.csv(file="fmeasures.txt",head=FALSE,sep=",")
labels <- read.csv(file="labels.txt",head=FALSE,sep=",")
```

Then I apply the Wilcoxon test with the following line

```
pairwise.wilcox.test(fmeasures, labels, p.adj = "bonf", paired= TRUE)
```

And I have the following error:

```
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
Calls: pairwise.wilcox.test -> factor -> as.factor -> factor ->   sort.list
Execution halted
```

By the way, labels is an array of strings.

The label file is [here](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~ra023169/labels-cpen-R.txt) and fmeasure file is [here](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~ra023169/fmeasures-cpen-R.txt)

What is happening? How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you share your data?

Comment: @erasmortg can you please see my update?

Comment: Do you get any warning messages when you read `labels.txt`? Did you change the format of labels? By reading it like that you are getting a data.frame when you probably need a vector instead

Comment: No, I read it normally in R, the labels file were crated in a matlab environment as a vector of one line, is it possible to convert it to a one line vector in R?

Comment: > dim(labels) returns me [1]   1 170, it is an one line and 170 column vector, which is exactly I need. What is the problem here?

Comment: see the answer i posted, let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, by reading `labels.txt` from that call, you get a `data.frame` with 170 columns. Try this instead:

```
pairwise.wilcox.test(fmeasures, unlist(labels), p.adj = "bonf", paired= TRUE)
```

You can see that `str(unlist(labels))` is a factor of 17 levels:

```
#Factor w/ 17 levels "dct","hierarch_sift",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:170] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" ...
```

Edit:

For completeness sake, `fmeasures` needs to be transformed into a numeric vector, as the `read.csv()` original call gives the same result as with `labels.txt` (a `data.frame` with 170 columns). A complete solution is therefore:

```
pairwise.wilcox.test(as.numeric(fmeasures), unlist(labels), p.adj = "bonf", paired= TRUE)
```

Comment: Now I have this error: Error in wilcox.test.default(xi, xj, paired = paired, ...) : 
  'x' must be numeric
Calls: pairwise.wilcox.test ... compare.levels -> wilcox.test -> wilcox.test.default. My fmeasures variable is not numeric?

Comment: try `as.numeric(fmeasures)`

Comment: It worked, just one more question. Here, the table is supposed to be 17x17, why it is 16x16?

Comment: I am not very familiar with the test, my guess it's either 17 factors don't lead to pairwise comparisons so one has to be dropped, or you need a certain number of degrees of freedom to calculate it